# SQL query help on joining 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of items and another table with item groups (not all items are in a group).

I want to get all from the items table and if it exists in the groups table, I only want to get one item per group please show me SQL query for this.

Comment: include your table structure with sample data and expected output and what you tried so far?

Comment: Items table and ItemGroups table

Items table have itemid, ItemGroups have groupid and itemid,
want to get all itemids from Items table which dont exist in the ItemGroups table and if they are part of a group want only 1 itemid per group.

Comment: if one item is mapped with 2 different group then you need two rows for that item? or just one row

Comment: See the answer with working demo..Let me know, if thats what you want

Comment: lets say items table have item 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,89,10 and itemgroup table have group 1 have itemid 1,2 group 2 have itemid 4,5,6. now the results i want to get is 1,3,4,7,8,9,10

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

I am defining a sample items and itemGroups table.

items

itemID, itemName, ItemDescription

itemGroups

itemGroupId, itemGroupname, ItemGroupDescription, itemID

Now to get all items from the item table if it exists in the itemsgroups table you have to compare the itemID which should your primary key in items table and compare it to the foreigh key for items which should be stored in the item groups table. So the SQL query could look like this

select * from items
where itemID in (select itemID from itemGroups)

Your coloumns names might be different but this is the general concept

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table structure similar to this:

```
create table items (itemid int, itemname varchar2(50));

insert all 
  into items (itemid, itemname) values (1,'Apples')
  into items (itemid, itemname) values (2,'Bananas')
  into items (itemid, itemname) values (3,'Ford')
  into items (itemid, itemname) values (4,'Honda')
  into items (itemid, itemname) values (5,'Football')

select * from dual;


create table itemgroups (itemgroupid int, itemid int, itemgroupname varchar2(50));

insert all
into itemgroups (itemgroupid, itemid, itemgroupname) values (1,1,'Fruits')
into itemgroups (itemgroupid, itemid, itemgroupname) values (1,2,'Fruits')
into itemgroups (itemgroupid, itemid, itemgroupname) values (2,3,'Cars')
into itemgroups (itemgroupid, itemid, itemgroupname) values (2,4,'Cars')

select * from dual;
```

You could do a `left join` to get all the records from your `items` table (but only get one item per group). Then, do some kind of aggregation like `MAX` or `MIN` to only get one value per group like this:

```
select min(i.itemid) as itemid,
       min(i.itemname) as itemname,
       ig.itemgroupid,
       ig.itemgroupname
from items i
left join itemgroups ig on i.itemid = ig.itemid
group by ig.itemgroupid,
         ig.itemgroupname
order by min(i.itemid);
```

**Result:**

```
+--------+----------+-------------+---------------+
| itemid | itemname | itemgroupid | itemgroupname |
+--------+----------+-------------+---------------+
|      1 | Apples   | 1           | Fruits        |
|      3 | Ford     | 2           | Cars          |
|      5 | Football | (null)      | (null)        |
+--------+----------+-------------+---------------+
```

[<kbd>**SQL Fiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/56054/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a groupid stored with each item row, try this:

```
select *
from items i
where groupid is null or itemid = (
    select min(itemid) from items i2
    where i2.groupid = i.groupid
)
```

If you didn't establish the linkage that way you might have to take this approach:

```
select *
from items i
where itemid = (
    select coalesce(min(ig.itemid), i.itemid)
    from itemgroups ig
    where ig.groupid = (select groupid from itemgroups ig2 where ig2.itemid = i.itemid)
)
```